# javascript global page vars - is there such a thing?

Tags: javascript, templates, global-variables

I am attempting to create a HTML template using Firefox and would like certain variables easily accessible at the top of a page. I don't seem to be able to get this to work. Is it even possible?

For the code given below, I get...

> undefined 
> copyright undefined

For example

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var year = getFullYear() ;
    var pgTitle = "Page Title";
  </script>
</head

<body>
  <script>document.write("<h1>"+pgTitle+"</h1>");</script>
<footer>
  <script>document.write("copyright "+year);</script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `getFullYear` defined? Did you mean `new Date().getFullYear()`?

Comment: either way, same result...

Comment: Have you tried the snippet in my answer? It works fine.

Comment: So what was keeping pgTitle from printing? the first error?

Comment: Yes, the errors at the start were causing it to print `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks - all is good now!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `getFullYear` anywhere. You probably wanted `new Date().getFullYear()`.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var pgTitle = "Page Title";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>document.write("<h1>"+pgTitle+"</h1>");</script>
<footer>
  <script>document.write("copyright "+year);</script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var pgTitle = "Page Title";
  </script>
</head

<body>
  <script>document.write(`<h1>${pgTitle}</h1>`);</script>
<footer>
  <script>document.write("copyright "+ year);</script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `${page}`  that is called template literals way of writing a variable value in  between string.. When you want to print a variable value in between `""` read more here - https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-are-template-literals-5d08a50ef2e3